# How to create new column based on an equation and unique values from other column?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, unique

Imagine I have a dataframe like this one below. I would like to create a new column df['b'] with a specific equation that takes the maximum and minimum values of df['a']. The equation should be something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0.3, 0.1, 0.7, 0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.1, 0.6, 0.8, 0.2, 0.2],
                   'group':[1, 1, 3, 3, 5, 5, 3, 3, 6, 6, 1]})

equation = (df['a'] - df['a'].min()) / (df['a'].max() - df['a'].min())
```

Although, these maximum and minimum values should be related to the unique values in df['group']. So, we should get the max and min values for group 1, 3, 5 and 6 and then apply the equation on the related row of df['a'].

I managed to separate these values, but I don't know how to reproduce this idea.

```
a_max = df.groupby('group')['a'].max()
a_min = df.groupby('group')['a'].min()
```

The output should look like this:

```
     a     group   b
0   0.3      1     1
1   0.1      1     0
2   0.7      3     1
3   0.5      3     0.67
4   0.4      5     1
5   0.3      5     0
6   0.1      3     0
7   0.6      3     0.6
8   0.8      6     1
9   0.2      6     0
10  0.2      1     0.5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can precompute the max/min by group:

```
groups = df.groupby('group')['a']
amax, amin = groups.transform('max'), groups.transform('min')

df['b'] = (df['a']-amin)/(amax-amin)
```

Or use a custom function:

```
df['b'] = df.groupby('group')['a'].apply(lambda x: (x-x.min())/(x.max()-x.min()) )
```

The first approach is slightly more performant, while the second is shorter in terms of code.

Both would output:

```
      a  group         b
0   0.3      1  1.000000
1   0.1      1  0.000000
2   0.7      3  1.000000
3   0.5      3  0.666667
4   0.4      5  1.000000
5   0.3      5  0.000000
6   0.1      3  0.000000
7   0.6      3  0.833333
8   0.8      6  1.000000
9   0.2      6  0.000000
10  0.2      1  0.500000
```

Comment: That is perfect, my friend. Thank you a lot.

Comment: Maybe np.ptp ~ :-)